# Vertical Hex to ASCII Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, hex, ascii

Situation:

I have a GUI where i already convert a horizontal Hex into ASCII... But now i want to convert a vertical Hex to ASCII.

Does anyone have some ideas how i can solve this?

I already splited it:

```
vert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fintext5.setText("");

            String[] test = entertext3.getText().split("\\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<test.length; i++){
                System.out.prinln(test[i]);
            }
         }
    });
```

Code for horizontal Hex:

```
button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fintext5.setText("");
            String readout = entertext3.getText().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "");

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");               
            for (int i = 0; i < readout.length(); i += 2)
            {
                String str = readout.substring(i, i + 2);
                output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
            }
            fintext5.append(output.toString());
        }
    });
```

Example for vertical Hex(41 42 43 44 45 46):

```
4 4 4
1 2 3
4 4 4
4 5 6
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what this "vertical hex" would be?

Comment: Well, if `test[0].charAt(0)` is the _first_ digit of the first ASCII, where do you suppose you'd find the _second_ digit of that first ASCII?

Comment: maybe     test[1].chatAt(0) ?

Comment: but how do i get this in a loop? i dont know how many lines i will have.

Comment: Of course you know:  `test.length`.  The only tricky thing is that your outer loop needs to go in steps of 2, like this `for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i+=2)`.

Comment: ok and how do i code this test[0].charAt(0) in the loop? something like:

      for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i+=2){

      for (int j = 0; test[i].length; i++{

     test2 = test[i].charAt(j) + test[i+1].charAt(j+1);

    }

    }

Comment: 'test[i+1].charAt(j)', but basically, you've got the idea. Now you've got a two-digit hex number in `test2` that you can do the `parseInt` trick on to get a `char` value, append that char to a `StringBuilder`...

Comment: vert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ausgabe5.setText("");
    String[] test = eingabe3.getText().split("\\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i+=2) {
     for (int j = 0; j<=test[i].charAt(j); i++) {
      int test2 = Integer.parseInt(null, test[i+1].charAt(j)); 
      
      System.out.println(test2);
     
     }
    } 
   }
  });

what am i missing? NumberFormatExeption

Comment: You left out the radix argument `, 16` on your `parseInt` call.

Comment: ok. still getting this error:  The method parseInt(String, int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int, char)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting so lost, I'll just give you a working starting point:

```
vert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ausgabe5.setText(""); 
        String[] test = eingabe3.getText().split("\\n"); 
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < test[i].length(); j++) {
                String hex = "" + test[i].charAt(j) + test[i + 1].charAt(j);
                output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(hex,16));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    } 
});
```

Please look it over and ask about anything you don't understand.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I am getting the result i am looking for :D

Comment: oh, i just have 1 question what does this 16 at parseInt do?

Comment: It's the radix of the string: 16 for hexadecimal